# How to synchronize my new e-commerce database with my old physical inventory

Tags: mysql, sql, e-commerce, firebird

I am looking into getting an e-commerce solution. Developers have been telling me there is no easy way to synchronize my exististing inventory database, in Firebird, with the new e-commerce database they would create. 
I cannot get rid of my current database and only use the new e-commerce one. Would changing my Firebird database to SQL or mySQL ease the communication with my e-commerce solution?
Can't I just create a script in any language that updates both my databases when there's a change on either side?

Comment: _"Would changing my Firebird database to SQL or mySQL"_ ... that makes no sense, Firebird uses SQL as its query language. Did you instead mean Microsoft SQL Server? In any case, this is too broad and open-ended; without detailed knowledge of both systems this is impossible to really answer.

Comment: As an aside, if your inventory system requires a separate database, then synchronizing between different databases of the same DBMS (assuming your inventory system even supports something other than Firebird) or between two different DBMSes is probably of similar complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what database will be used for the e-commerce solution, but regardless, it should be pretty simple to accomplish what you want to do at the application level.  Run the SQL update commands against both databases (at the application level) and the two databases should stay pretty well synced.

This might take a little bit of work because the two systems may not have the exact same SQL support, but it should work fine. You also need to be careful about what type SQL commands you send to both databases to make sure they will be making exactly the same update in both DBs (and execute in the same order on both DBs).

Comment: That isn't a realistic option if multiple applications (maybe written by a third-party) are using that inventory database (eg that new e-commerce solution that probably needs up-to-date stock information, and maybe a warehouse management system which receives and ships items)

Comment: I guess it depends on how many applications are modifying the databases, based on the OP I assumed it was just one application, and that application needed two DBs synced.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have got some useful suggestion above.
If there are conflict between the DBMS or Database Structure still you could manage by API.
An API could play a bridge between the Inventory and eCommerce.That way you could be sync.